# E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7.4 while using Docker Compose

Tags: docker

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to build a Docker image with

```
  docker-compose up -d
```

I am getting the following errors

```
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libapache2-mod-php7.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libapache2-mod-php7.4'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-cli
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-cli'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-cli'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-fpm
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-fpm'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-fpm'
```

I tried to all Ubuntu source list from Ubuntu to get the packages but nothing seems to be working.

[image]

Added dockerfile as well.